How to download system PDBs of particular version/timestamp
I have a dump collected from a system that I don't have access to. Opening the dump in windbg shows incomplete callstack due to missing symbols for kernelbase.dll. I have set the symbol path - SRV*C:\WebSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
It should have been downloaded from Microsoft symbol server, but it has failed. This is a very frequent issue for system PDBs unable to download. This is causing a lot of problems as we are getting incomplete callstacks for crashes and unable to group them.
Where to download this version of PDB?
@MSFT Please root cause why the system PDBs are missing from MS symbols server so frequently.
The dll missing symbols in my dump :
0:000> lmvm KERNELBASE
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
00007ffb`b1f80000 00007ffb`b2094000   KERNELBASE T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: KERNELBASE.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
    Image name: KERNELBASE.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Fri Mar 15 09:57:06 2024 (65F3CE1A)
    CheckSum:         0011BB8C
    ImageSize:        00114000
    File version:     6.3.9600.21914
    Product version:  6.3.9600.21914
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4

load attempt with sym noisy on:
0:000> .reload /f KERNELBASE.dll
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x32
         c:\mssymbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         KERNELBASE.dll
         65F3CE1A114000
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\mssymbols\KERNELBASE.dll\65F3CE1A114000\KERNELBASE.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\mssymbols\KERNELBASE.dll\65F3CE1A114000\KERNELBASE.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\mssymbols\KERNELBASE.dll\65F3CE1A114000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/KERNELBASE.dll/65F3CE1A114000/KERNELBASE.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/KERNELBASE.dll/65F3CE1A114000/KERNELBASE.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/KERNELBASE.dll/65F3CE1A114000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: C:\Temp\Dumps\KERNELBASE.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll image header does not match memory image header.
DBGENG:  C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll - Couldn't map image from disk.
Unable to load image C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll, Win32 error 0n2


the url should be https. You should get everything with: .symfix and .reload which sets the MS symbol server. Does that work? Are you having internet access on the machine where you analyze the dump? You can set !sym noisy to see more details.

@AloisKraus https did not help. Added the output of sym noisy to question

Is that a minidump? In that case you need also to have a folder with the matching binaries to see the correct disassembled code. You are downloading the image from cerner symbol store and not from MS. Try again with .symfix and a reload of kernelbase.dll

It failed to load from the ms symbol store - https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

@HansPassant: 6.3.9600 should be Windows Server 2012 R2 which is out of service. Potentially paying customers get still security fixes but the symbols are not uploaded anymore I guess?
